# How to use images from themes/third_party folder in a plugin?

Tags: plugin, image, themes

I am writing a simple plugin and I want to use some images within the plugin. I assume that the *themes/third_party*-folder is the right place for those. How can I use them? I cannot link to them directly (e.g. `<img src="/themes/third_party/..."`) because the folder is not directly accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExpressionEngine have [Path Constants](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/constants.html). You can use PATH_THIRD_THEMES. You should have image path like:

```
$img = "<img src='".PATH_THIRD_THEMES."IMAGE_NAME' />";
```

I hope, it would help you.

Comment: Path constants :)

Comment: corrected it. sorry for misspell :) ...

Comment: Thanks! With `URL_THIRD_THEMES` it works!